# Find all the nodes which does not have transitive occurrence?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where the nodes is the stations and the relationships between the stations is the trips of a bike. I wanted to find all the patterns where any station `a` is connected to station `b`, `b` is connected to `c`, but `c` is not directly connected to `a`.

```
(a)-[:Related_to]->(b)
(b)-[:Related_to]->(c)
```

but `a` is not related to `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using  `WHERE NOT` predicate.

```
MATCH (a)-[:Related_to]-(b)-[:Related_to]-(c)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:Related_to]-(c)
```

Update:

If you want to get only the top 10 transitive nodes you can use `limit`.

```
MATCH (a)-[:Related_to]-(b)-[:Related_to]-(c)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:Related_to]-(c)
WITH c,size((c)-[Related_to]->()) as nr_of_outgoing_rels order by nr_of_outgoing_rels desc
RETURN c limit 10
```